# Why does numpy.zeros takes up little space

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

I am wondering why numpy.zeros takes up such little space?

```
x = numpy.zeros(200000000)
```

This takes up no memory while,

```
x = numpy.repeat(0,200000000)
```

takes up around 1.5GB. Does numpy.zeros create an array of empty pointers? 
If so, is there a way to set the pointer back to empty in the array after changing it in cython? If I use:

```
x = numpy.zeros(200000000)
x[0:200000000] = 0.0
```

The memory usage goes way up. Is there a way to change a value, and then change it back to the format numpy.zeros originally had it in python or cython?

Comment: How are you measuring the memory each array uses? If `x = numpy.zeros(200000000)` then `x.nbytes` is `1600000000` on my machine. For `x = numpy.repeat(0, 200000000)` half that memory is used (the `int32` datatype instead of the `float64` datatype is used when creating the array).

Comment: [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/449560/2359271) (pay special attention to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3373511/2359271))

Comment: I was just watching the change in the activity monitor

Comment: FYI: I think I just ran into the same thing on window 2012 server with python 3.7.2 and some recent numpy version. The interresting question is: what happens in case of `x[0:10]=1`. Does the whole array get allocated or only the required slice? Will check tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are you using Linux? Linux has lazy allocation of memory. The underlying calls to `malloc` and `calloc` in numpy always 'succeed'. No memory is actually allocated until the memory is first accessed.

The `zeros` function will use `calloc` which zeros any allocated memory before it is first accessed. Therfore, numpy need not explicitly zero the array and so the array will be lazily initialised. Whereas, the `repeat` function cannot rely on `calloc` to initialise the array. Instead it must use `malloc` and then copy the repeated to all elements in the array (thus forcing immediate allocation).