# Numpy memory error

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

I'm running into a memory error issue with numpy. The following line of code seems to be the issue:

```
self.D_r = numpy.diag(1/numpy.sqrt(self.r))
```

Where self.r is a relatively small numpy array.

The interesting thing is I monitored the memory usage and the process took up at most 3% of the RAM on the machine. So I'm thinking there's something that is killing the script before all the RAM is taken up because there is an expectation that the process will do so. If anybody has any ideas I would be very grateful.

**Edit 1:**

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path_to_file/my_script.py", line 82, in <module>
mca_X = mca.mca(X)
File "/path_to_file/mca.py", line 54, in __init__
self.D_r = numpy.diag(1/numpy.sqrt(self.r.values))
File "/path_to_file/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 302, in diag
res = zeros((n, n), v.dtype)
MemoryError
```

Running the script on KDD Cup 99 data (with one-hot-encoded nominal variables).

Comment: Could you add the exact error message?

Comment: I think Python won't occupy the memory if it sees that you won't have enough so the memory usage is probably not relevant. Could you give a minimal working example with data that can be tested upon?

Comment: How small is relatively small? 100 entries? 1 million entries? A trillion? I find numpy doesn't like it if you pass a 1D array into diag which is more than 100,000 elements, as it is too big.

Comment: break up the offending line into its individual computations.  i.e., take the square root on one line, then do the inversion on a second line, etc.  see which of those lines raises the error.

Comment: Is `self.r` a 1D or 2D array?

Comment: Great, question @MikeMüller. That's the answer! It's a 1-d array, which means diag is making it into a 2-d array. The 1-d array was not large but the 2-d array is massive (~2TB).

Comment: Is there a way to do this as a sparse matrix operation?

Comment: Bear in mind that the kernel will [allocate memory lazily when you call `np.zeros`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27582592/1461210). You probably won't see your memory usage increase until you actually start writing to elements in your empty array.

Comment: *"Is there a way to do this as a sparse matrix operation?"* That depends on what operations you actually want to perform using `self.D_r`. You could use [`scipy.sparse.diags`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html) to create a sparse diagonal matrix ([`dia_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dia_matrix.html)), which supports basic arithmetic and linear algebra ops, but not direct indexing. You can read about other sparse matrix classes [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the argument to `np.diag()` is a 1D, it creates a 2D array, using the 1D array as diagonal:

> Signature: np.diag(v, k=0)
>
> ### Parameters
>
> ```
>  v : array_like
>    If `v` is a 2-D array, return a copy of its `k`-th diagonal.
>    If `v` is a 1-D array, return a 2-D array with `v` on the `k`-th
>    diagonal.
> ```

This squares the memory size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

if `self.r` is a 1D *little array* of more than 51000 éléments it can create a memory error :

```
In [85]: a=np.diag(arange(5e4))

In [86]: a.shape
Out[86]: (50000, 50000)

In [88]: a.size*a.itemsize
Out[88]: 20 000 000 000 # 20 Go

In [87]: a=np.diag(arange(5.1e4))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError
```